# Angular 9 - how to properly encode + sign in URL parameter

Tags: spring-boot, url, character-encoding, urlencode, angular9

I spent many hours without success. I know it's a common problem, many solutions but for me works only Interceptor that I want to avoid.

My service - here I get email with plus like john.doe+100@gmail.com

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UsersHttpService {
  httpParams = new HttpParams({encoder: new CustomEncoder()});
    removeUsersFromGroup(groupId: string, email: string): Observable<any> {
        console.log(email); //john.doe+100@gmail.com
        let parsedEmail = encodeURI(email); //one of many attempts
        return this.http.delete(`${this.env.URI}/monitoring/api/v1/groups/${groupId}/users/`, {
          params: {
            groupId,
            email: email.replace(' ', '+')
          },
        });
      }
```

And my CustomEncoder:

```
export class CustomEncoder implements HttpParameterCodec {
  encodeKey(key: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(key);
  }

  encodeValue(value: string): string {
    // console.log('encodeValue encodeValue');
    // console.log(value);
    // console.log(encodeURIComponent(value));
    return encodeURIComponent(value);
  }

  decodeKey(key: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(key);
  }

  decodeValue(value: string): string {
    // console.log('decodeValue decodeValue');
    // console.log(value);
    // console.log(decodeURIComponent(value));
    return decodeURIComponent(value);
  }
}
```

When I send request from Angular then in the Network tab in web browser I see:

```
DELETE https://myapp/groups/d39a4f50-8ebd-11ea-a9ae-5103b15ad73b/users/?groupId=d39a4f50-8ebd-11ea-a9ae-5103b15ad73b&email=john.doe 100@gmail.com
```

with a space! What's wrong? Were is the problem? IN the console I get email with + but in Network tab without space instead of + sign.

My params are properly encoded (there is 200 status from backend (spring boot), email with +) ONLY when I use global interceptor (which should be avoided):

```
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpParams,
  HttpRequest,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {CustomEncoder} from "./customEncoder";

@Injectable()
export class EncodeHttpParamsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const params = new HttpParams({
      encoder: new CustomEncoder(),
      fromString: req.params.toString(),
    });
    return next.handle(req.clone({params}));
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea??? I tried to use:
return this.http.delete(`${this.env.ORBITAL_URI}/monitoring/api/v1/groups/${groupId}/users/`, {
params: {
groupId,
email: encodeURI(email) //or encodeURIComponent(email)
},
});

and then in Network tab I see something like john.doe%2B%40gmail.com but I get 500 error from backend

Answer (score 0):

My solution - without any interceptor:

```
 removeUsersFromGroup(groupId: string, email: string): Observable<any> {
    const params = new HttpParams({
      encoder: new CustomEncoder(),
      fromObject: {
        groupId,
        email,
      },
    });
    return this.http.delete(`${this.env.URI}/myapp/v1/groups/${groupId}/users/`, {
      params: params,
    });
  }
```

Now it works as expected:)